# Swift 3: how to write this for(;;) loop

Tags: for-loop, swift3

Looks like Apple doesn't like C loops, but doesn't provide good approach over it (or I couldn't find it). I have such loop to go from some view to the root in UI hierarchy:

```
for var parentView = view; parentView != nil; parentView = parentView.parent {
    ...
}
```

How to write this in Swift 3 manner?

Comment: It's really **not Apple** who doesn't like C loops, but [Erica Sadun](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md), Andy Matuschak (Khan Academy), Keith Smiley (Lyft), and others in the mailing list. Chris Lattner (Apple) is just open to them. Finally the committee agreed to remove it.

Comment: Please don't add the solution as "Update" to the question. If you want to share your own solution, you can post an answer.

Comment: @FelixSFD thanks for advice, extracted that to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a way to do it in Swift 3:

```
var parentView: View! = view
while parentView != nil {
    // Do stuff
    parentView = parentView.parent
}
```

If you want to group the loop progression stuff next to `while` and not at the end of block, you may use `defer`, like this:

```
var parentView: View! = view
while parentView != nil {
    defer { parentView = parentView.parent }        
    // Do stuff
}
```

If you want to limit the scope of `parentView`, you can encapsulate everything in a `do` block:

```
do {
    var parentView: View! = view
    while parentView != nil {
        defer { parentView = parentView.parent }        
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

But it's quite verbose so you could define a new generic function for similar loops, like this:

```
func kindaCStyleLoop<T>(first: T, obtainNext: T -> T?, action: T -> ()) {
    var current: T! = first
    repeat {
        action(current)
        current = obtainNext(current)
    } while current != nil
}

kindaCStyleLoop(view, obtainNext: { $0.parent }) {
    // Do stuff with $0
}
```

And a last one that relies on `GeneratorType` and `SequenceType` to enable using the for-in-loop syntax:

```
struct CStyleGenerator<T> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {
    let getNext: T -> T?
    var current: T!

    init(first: T, getNext: T -> T?) {
        self.getNext = getNext
        self.current = first
    }

    mutating func next() -> T? {
        defer {
            if current != nil {
                current = getNext(current)
            }
        }
        return current
    }
}

for parentView in CStyleGenerator(first: view, getNext: { $0.parent }) {
    // Do stuff with parentView
}
```

Comment: Optional can be safely unwrapped inside the while loop

Comment: I updated my answer to use an implicit optional instead of an explicit one.

Comment: This will crash when parentView becomes nil finally. You can leave it as it was before, or unwrap the optional inside the while loop

Comment: It doesn't crash on the [IBM Swift Sandbox 3.0-dev](https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mmc=developerWorks-_-dWdevcenter-_-swift-_-lp#/repl). The code I tested is [here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/6b20ed840f61d3c0835a5ec4a3052d05d7fb57ce7e5b4e8b9b57ae20ccf235a4).

Comment: not nice :/ we declare variable outside of the loop, make iteration in the end of code block, and at all have too many lines of code

Comment: Not beautiful but it does work. The C-style for loop is somewhat unreadable to me because of its length and it can be much worse if, unlike you the original developer does not use proper spacing. (dear downvoter, why the downvote?)

Comment: I updated my solution with a defer proposition, not a lot different but at least, everything is grouped around the while.

Comment: @Valentin, `defer` looks fine here. Any idea how to hide `parentView` into `while` code-block? Before swift 3 we could declare it as `var` in `while` statement, but Apple forbids this too :/

Comment: I added 2 more solutions :) One where you put everything in a do-block to limit parentView scope and another where you define a generic function for this kind of loops. I don't think you'll be able to define parentView in the while loop because the condition and the block might be executed multiple times.

Comment: Thank you man! Especially for the last generic function - wonder how gently we can wrap our code for general for-loop purposes!

Comment: You're welcome :) I added a last solution with Generator/SequenceType which enables using the for-in-loop syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Correct but too-late answer: there are built-in functions in Swift 3 which provide the solution:

```
public func sequence<T>(first: T, next: (T) -> T?) -> UnfoldSequence<T, (T?, Bool)>
public func sequence<T, State>(state: State, next: (inout State) -> T?) -> UnfoldSequence<T, State>
```

We can use them in this manner:

```
sequence(first: view, next: {
    // do something with $0...
    return $0.superview
})
```

Comment: You do not need the for in if you are not using it. Use only the sequence function.

Answer (score 0):

For instance

```
for view in views where view.superview != nil {
}
```